# SharePoint, register a review without changing version number

Tags: sharepoint, version-control

I am using SharePoint's in-built version control as a means of identifying the current approved versions of procedures, so I get x.y as minor (draft) versions and x.0 as the major (approved) versions.  This bit works fine.

Our ISO 9001 auditor has asked how we would demonstrate that quality procedures have been reviewed.  There will no doubt be many instances for our company in the future where procedures are around ten to twenty years old, but have not needed changing.  Unfortunately this then would give the impression that there hasn't been a review of the document.

A clumsy solution to this would simply be to keep a record of all the documents and have a review date in a spreadsheet then record when the review has been done.  It would be far easier for me if SharePoint could look after this for us, however, what I don't want to do is have to check out a document to review it and then have publish as the next major version as proof that it has been reviewed.

My question is: is there a way in SharePoint's version control to record that a review of a document has been conducted but no changes made?

I hope my question is clear, but if you have specific questions please ask.  Many thanks

Comment: To be clear, do you want to track the review date in a column on the library?

Comment: If that's a possibility then yes, otherwise any other way that would demonstrate a review has taken place is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Add another field in your document lib. Call it Reviewed and make it Yes/No type.
Edit document properties when you make a review and update the field accordingly.
Add another field, type = dateTime. When editing document properties, insert the date of the review.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I figure this wouldn't allow for recording of numerous reviews though, say once every three years over a period without changes, but I could have a free text column named "Review History" that would do the job.